# Understanding indexing of data frame with colon operator

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that is from the [predictive maintenance R Notebook example](https://gallery.azure.ai/Notebook/Predictive-Maintenance-Modelling-Guide-R-Notebook-1) by MS.

Now they show how to subset this data.frame like this (showing some of the first rows and some of the last with just one line of code instad of using `head()` or `tail()`):

```
> errors[c(1:3, nrow(errors)-3:1),]
                datetime machineID errorID
1    2015-01-03 07:00:00         1  error1
2    2015-01-03 20:00:00         1  error3
3    2015-01-04 06:00:00         1  error5
3916 2015-12-04 02:00:00       100  error1
3917 2015-12-08 06:00:00       100  error2
3918 2015-12-08 06:00:00       100  error3
```

They want to output

I do unterstand what the colon operator does. But I do not really understand what it does in this example. Because: while `4:1` will return

```
> 4:1
[1] 4 3 2 1
```

and

```
nrow(errors):1
   [1] 3919 3918 3917 3916 3915 3914 3913 3912 3911 3910 3909 3908 3907 3906 3905 3904 3903
  [18] 3902 3901 3900 3899 3898 3897 3896 3895 3894 3893 3892 3891 3890 3889 3888 3887 3886
...
```

Then the following does not return what I would expect:

```
> nrow(errors)-3:1
[1] 3916 3917 3918
```

I would have expected that it returns the same long list as before, but starting with the index at `nrow(errors)-3`. So something like:

```
nrow(errors):1
       [1] 3916 3915 3914 3913 3912 3911 3910 3909 3908 3907 3906 3905 3904 3903
    ...
```

What do I understand wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `(nrow(errors)-3):1`, take a look at https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html

Comment: The colon operator is evaluated first. Instead of BODMAS, you now need to remember BO:DMAS.

Comment: See `?Syntax` for a table giving operator precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @markus and @Aaron Hayman and @G Grothendieck

The colon operator is evaluated first. So that

```
> 3:1
[1] 3 2 1
```

And `nrow(errors)` will return `3919`.
Then subtracting `3:1` will give a vector like `c(3919-3, 3919-2, 3919-1)`

And by thinking this over again, I realize it should be:

```
> nrow(errors)-2:0
[1] 3917 3918 3919
```

to really get the **last** three lines, like in the following:

```
> errors[c(1:3, nrow(errors)-2:0),]
                datetime machineID errorID
1    2015-01-03 07:00:00         1  error1
2    2015-01-03 20:00:00         1  error3
3    2015-01-04 06:00:00         1  error5
3917 2015-12-08 06:00:00       100  error2
3918 2015-12-08 06:00:00       100  error3
3919 2015-12-22 03:00:00       100  error3
```

This helped understanding. Thanks!